# Unable to publish Self Hosted Private App using Enterprise account

Tags: android-management-api

After generating APK definition file, i tried to publish it on play console by following below reference

Reference : [Publish an externally hosted app in the Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182?hl=en&ref_topic=9495939)

step-1) Sign in to the Play Console with your organization's administrator account.

step-2) Create a private app by [publishing to your own organization](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#publishprivate). Ensure you add at least one organization to Private app access.

step-3) Click Upload external APKs.

**Issue** : In step-2 we need to create new app in play console. I'm unable to create new app when login play console with enterprise account(**Not an Android Developer Account**) create app button is noneditable, do i need to add any other settings to make it editable.

[image: Play console logged-in with enterprise account]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have android developer account for creating apps, there is a fees of 25$ to create developer account.

Comment: Thank you, will try with developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use your enterprise account to create apps in the Play Developer Console, you need to have a Google Play Developer Account to do this. However, you can use the following steps to create an externally hosted app:

1. Upload an apk via iFrame with the same app id as the app you want to host externally. This will essentially act as a “dummy” app.
2. Generate a JSON metadata file using the steps described  [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182?hl=en&ref_topic=9495939). Make sure that the version of this externally hosted apk is higher than the one uploaded via iFrame.
3. On the iFrame, click the app and open the Play Developer Console via the “Make advanced edits” button.
4. Create a new release by navigating through the sidebar, then Production > Create new release.
5. Upload your JSON metadata file under “App bundles and APK”.
   Then, Save > Review Release > Start rollout to production.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion,  Is there any clear documentation or reference for Generate a JSON metadata, and publishing the generated file using (Google Play Developer API ) by code instead of play console way.